# редирект на английскую версию сайта в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт https://one.ru/, который сразу редиректится на https://two.ru. После этого сервер отдает статику и на клиенте запускается SPA на ангуляре. Нужно, чтобы при вводе в адресной строке https://one.ru/en происходил редирект на https://two.ru/en. Исходный файл .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?one\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://two.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
</IfModule>
```

По аналогии добавляю такие строчки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?one\.ru/en //еще пробовал \/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://two.ru/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

При вводе адреса https://one.ru/ все работает корректно. Но при вводе https://one.ru/en редиректа не происходит. При этом SPA корректно запускается, только вот на странице https://one.ru/en.

Как заставить сервер делать редирект на https://two.ru/en?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы просто не перекидывать все адреса

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^two\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://two.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Вот так выглядит на рабочем сайте

```
# Редирект *festival22.ru* на фестиваль22.рф*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} robots.txt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xn--22-6kchosx8bjr9g\.xn--p1ai$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn--22-6kchosx8bjr9g.xn--p1ai/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: блин, я вижу, что это работает. но я ничего не понял....

Comment: @muturgan Если домен не содержит `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^two\.ru$ [NC]` то переадресовывать клиента на `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://two.ru/$1 [L,R=301]` со всем урлом

Comment: ясно, спасибо Вам!